# Find function for asp:FileUpLoad returns allways null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload, find

I have Created a Asp:FileUpload control in aspx page, I try to access the Control from Javascript using this code,

in Aspx page

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUp" runat="server" />
```

in Javascript

```
var vbsfileupload = $find("<%= fileUp.ClientID %>");
```

but the vbsfileupload is always null value.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe `$find` is a function at all. Try selecting the element using `getElementById`:

```
var vbsfileupload = document.getElementById("#<%= fileUp.ClientID %>");
```

Assuming you are running this part of the script *after* the element has loaded, `vbsfileupload` should now hold the desired element.

Comment: @AkshayJoy I just realized you're not using jQuery at all. Updated my answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the same,,?? I am using Infragitics control Library